# get Dynamic Organisation Id in validation Rule

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule, user-management, organization

I want to implement validation rule whew i need to check organisation id.
My validation rule contains (organisation.id='005223323')
Can anybody tell me is there any way to take the organisation id dynamically.

Comment: you mean to take hard coded value `'005223323'` dynamiically?

Comment: yes.pranay.....

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [global variable](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&type=5) documentation, it has Organization variable which you can use to get the information of company information dynamically. Org Id can be fetched with `$Organization.Id`.

Comment: But, a word of caution... when cloning an org, the value in the string can be modified if the hard-coded org Id matches the org Id being cloned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hierarchical Custom settings in validation. This ensures your metadata is not hardcoded.

Thus your validation will looks something like

```
$Organization.Id=$Setup.YourHierachicalCustomSetting__c.CustomOrgId__c
```

https://salesforceprofs.com/hierarchy-custom-setting-in-validation-rules/